# How to decrypt windows password with SAM and SYSTEM files?

Tags: password-cracking, windows-10

Suppose we have access to SAM and SYSTEM file, I want to decrypt the password. I'd like not to use any third-party software and write my own algorithm. Is there a way to do so?

Comment: Have you looked at software that does do this and determined what they do?

Comment: The available tools explain the process and how to do it. I'm not sure why you want to re-invent the wheel, but you can use the python script in the linked answer to work it out.